# Difference between test and train set

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset which has 24 hours traffic. i am using 60% for training and 40% for testing. I am observing some similar instances in both sets. I wanted to know, should test set and train set be completely different from each?

Answer (score 0):

Yes they should. Else when your model will be trained on train data and will see similar data in test dataset it will "increase" accuracy. But for other data (which not contain duplicates from train set) it can have much more lover accuracy.